# Parse only text within a div class python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

so what I wanna do is from reading the source code, search for the div class named "gsc_prf_il", then within this div class, extract only the text, ignoring the href link. e.g.

```
<div class="gsc_prf_il"><a href="/citations?view_op=view_org&hl=en&org=13784427342582529234">McGill University</a></div>
```

But when I use this code, it doesn't work, only gives me error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(p.readlines()[0], 'html.parser')
s=soup.find(id='gsc_prf_il')
scholar_info['department']= s.contents
```

So then I tried this:

```
scholar_info['department']=[s.find('a')['href'], s.find('a').contents[0]]
```

It doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just find the *div* and pull the text, you are looking for `soup.find(id='gsc_prf_il')` which is looking for an element with an `id` of `gsc_prf_il` not a div with that class:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_283660.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<div class="gsc_prf_il"><a href="/citations?view_op=view_org&hl=en&org=13784427342582529234">McGill University</a></div>""")
```

So use `class_="gsc_prf_il"`:

```
print(soup.find("div", class_="gsc_prf_il").text) -> McGill University
```

Or use a css selector:

```
print(soup.select_one("div.gsc_prf_il").text) -> McGill University
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!